# transform a js object into a new object with an other fotm

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, typescript

I want to write a function that transfers this object

```
const BEFORE = [
  {
    book_id: 1001,
    book_title: "L'enfant perdue",
    subgender: { Thriller: true },
  },
  {
    book_id: 1002,
    book_title: "La vérité sort de la bouche du cheval",
    subgender: { Thriller: true, Autobiographie: true },
  },
  {
    book_id: 1003,
    book_title: "Le pain nu",
    subgender: { Autobiographie: true },
  },
];
```

to be like a thing like that

```
const AFTER =  {
    Thriller: {
      subgender: "Thriller",
      books: [
        {
          book_id: 1001,
          book_title: "L'enfant perdue",
          subgender: { Thriller: true },
        },
        {
          book_id: 1002,
          book_title: "La vérité sort de la bouche du cheval",
          subgender: { Thriller: true, Autobiographie: true },
        },
      ],
      Autobiographie: {
        subgender: "Autobiographie",
        books: [
          {
            book_id: 1002,
            book_title: "La vérité sort de la bouche du cheval",
            subgender: { Thriller: true, Autobiographie: true },
          },
          {
            book_id: 1003,
            book_title: "Le pain nu",
            subgender: { Autobiographie: true },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
```

I tried with Array.reduce, but I don't know how to render this.
If anyone has any hindsight on this
I want to extract subgender as a key and add subgender value, so can i use map to loop the subgender or reduce

thank you

Comment: Could you post what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly standard 'group by' situation which can be addressed with a [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) call.

The snippet retrieves the 'subgenders' [sic] from the [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) of the objects in the array filtered by whether they are `true` or not, checks the accumulator for an existing property otherwise declares one, and then pushes the object into the `books` array.

```js
const input = [{ book_id: 1001, book_title: "L'enfant perdue", subgender: { Thriller: true }, }, { book_id: 1002, book_title: "La vérité sort de la bouche du cheval", subgender: { Thriller: true, Autobiographie: true }, }, { book_id: 1003, book_title: "Le pain nu", subgender: { Autobiographie: true }, },];

const result = input.reduce((a, o) => {
  const subgenders = Object.keys(o.subgender).filter(k => o.subgender[k]);

  subgenders.forEach(subgender => {
    a[subgender] = a[subgender] || { subgender, books: [] };
    // or using logical nullish assignment
    //a[subgender] ??= { subgender, books: [] };
    
    a[subgender].books.push({ ...o });
  })

  return a;
}, {});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```